# How to relate multiple rows from one table to a row in another table?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have various tables (e.g. individual drivers, vehicles, transactions, etc.). Sometimes, rows in one table can be associated with more than one row in another table. For example, the same driver can be associated with several vehicles and several transactions. Since it isn't a good idea to have columns with multiple values, how can I relate these records?

Comment: Create a bridge table that has the id's of both tables as foreign keys and add all of the records there.

Comment: Google "one-to-may relationship"

Comment: AKA *Associative Entity*  it is a DB Design/relationship thing not a SQL thing

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, everyone. I wasn't sure what to look for because I didn't know what to ask, but now I have a starting point.